# yii2 hide model name from url in GET Method

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a script that switches images in a certain amount of time. But on my page, the images are not displayed because they get method gets the wrong URL: ***GET http://schedule/monitor/img/math/22.03/22.03.JPG 404 (Not Found)***. The correct URL should be like this:
***http://schedule/img/math/22.03/22.03.JPG***. How to hide the model name from image src when I get this from js script?

**slider.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/monitor/insert_math',
        data: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var i = 0;          //START POINT
            var unfiltered_images = data;   //UNFILTERED IMAGES ARRAY
            var time = 30000;   //TIME BETWEEN SWITCH

            var images = unfiltered_images.filter(file => file.endsWith('.JPG')); //FILE FILTER BY EXTENSION
            console.log(images);

            if (images.length != 0) {

                function changeImg() {

                    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[i];

                    if (i < images.length - 1) { //CHECK IF INDEX IS UNDER MAX
                        i++; //ADD 1 TO INDEX
                    } else {
                        i = 0; //RESET BACK TO 0
                    }
                    setTimeout(changeImg, time); //RUN FUNCTION EVERY X SECONDS
                }

                window.onload = changeImg(); //RUN FUNCTION WHEN PAGE LOADS
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**1311.php**

```
<div class="info_block">
      <img id="slide" height="626px">
</div>
```

**Path to PHP file:**

[image]

Comment: You can use this > Url::to(['/img/math/22.03/22.03.JPG'],true) to avoid module name

Comment: it's right. But my script is in a separate file 'slider.js' and image src generated automatically **document.getElementById('slide').src = images[i];**. How to change src in js file?

Comment: please provide server side code. or mention response data

Comment: the ajax data is an array of paths to images: ["img/math/22.03\22.03 (2).JPG", "img/math/22.03\22.03.JPG"]

Comment: try with this -----> document.getElementById('slide').src = "/"+images[i];

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works, it was pretty simple... why didn't I come up with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**document.getElementById('slide').src = "/"+images[i];**

answer by [Shringiraj Dewangan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7450047/shringiraj-dewangan)